# Flutter How to get all docs and collections

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I need to get my data as in the path I am showing.

> shipment collection > collection id (also this is user id) > myYuks collection > doc's id > doc's field

[image]

[image]

I have a YukModel and I have a Database Service.

```
My YukModel codes;
class YukModel {
  String? yukID;
  String? yukBaslik;
  String? icerik;
  int? agirlik;
  Timestamp? createTime;
  String? aracTipi;
  bool? onayDurumu;

  YukModel(
      {this.yukID,
      this.yukBaslik,
      this.icerik,
      this.agirlik,
      this.createTime,
      this.aracTipi,
      this.onayDurumu});

  YukModel.fromDocumentSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
    yukID = documentSnapshot.id;
    yukBaslik = documentSnapshot.get('yukBaslik');
    icerik = documentSnapshot.get('icerik');
    agirlik = documentSnapshot.get('agirlik');
    createTime = documentSnapshot.get('createTime');
    aracTipi = documentSnapshot.get('aracTipi');
    onayDurumu = documentSnapshot.get('onayDurumu');
  }
}
```

A fragment of my Database Code;

```
class DataBaseFB {
  final FirebaseFirestore _firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  


getYukListFromDB() {
    _firebaseFirestore.collection("shipment").get().then((querySnapshot) async {
      for (var resultA in querySnapshot.docs) {
        await _firebaseFirestore
            .collection("shipment")
            .doc(resultA.id)
            .collection("myYuks")
            .get()
            .then((querySnapshot) async {
          for (var resultB in querySnapshot.docs) {
            await _firebaseFirestore
                .collection("shipment")
                .doc(resultA.id)
                .collection("myYuks")
                .doc(resultB.id)
                .get()
                .then((value) {
              YukModel yukModel = YukModel.fromDocumentSnapshot(value);
              debugPrint("-----------------------YUKLER---------------\n"
                  "yukBaslik: ${yukModel.yukID}\n"
                  "iccerik: ${yukModel.icerik}");
            });
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

}

And I tried to acces getYukListFromDB with a button in HomePage. Then I got this error;

> Exception has occurred. StateError (Bad state: field does not exist
> within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform)

What should I do ?

Comment: The error shows that the field you are searching does not exist in the data model. You don't need to create a model class inside the flutter app when you are working with firebase you can directly listen to the real time database. and fetch specific data from the database

Comment: But I perefer to seperate my all tree.  So, the fields are already exist in Firebase and YukModel. Sorry but your answer is not solving my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved problem myself. Here is code from Database file;

```
getYukListFromDB() async {
    _firebaseFirestore
        .collection('shipment')
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
      for (var docA in querySnapshot.docs) {
        debugPrint("shipment altındaki docs idsi = " + docA.id);
        _firebaseFirestore
            .collection('shipment')
            .doc(docA.id)
            .collection('myYuks')
            .get()
            .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
          for (var docB in querySnapshot.docs) {
            debugPrint("myYuk altındaki docs idsi = " + docB.id);
            _firebaseFirestore
                .collection('shipment')
                .doc(docA.id)
                .collection('myYuks')
                .doc(docB.id)
                .get()
                .then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
              Map<String, dynamic> mapData =
                  documentSnapshot.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
              if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
                debugPrint("icerik =  ${mapData['icerik']}");
                debugPrint('doc var');
              } else {
                debugPrint('doc yok');
              }
            });
          }
        });
      }
    });
```